# Setting up Bamboo SVN commit build trigger

Tags: visualsvn-server, bamboo, build-triggers

Bamboo CI has a build in feature of having the subversion program trigger a build in bamboo when someone commits to the repository.   I followed the instructions of what to put in the post commit hook but I am not sure what the 2 arguments are supposed to be for the postcommitbuildtrigger.sh file.  Lets say the project name is TEST and the build name is TESTBUILD and the server url is http://localhost:8085.  I wrote this in the post commit hook command line.

```
/<pathtopostcommit.sh> TEST TESTBUILD
```

### Question

The post commit .sh file is on a windows machine. It could be because windows doesnt run .sh files but if thats so does anyone know how to set up this trigger on windows?

Also, I think this will trigger a build immediatly?  Is is possible to trigger bamboo to run a poll instead so the build will obey the quiet period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to write your own scripts. Bamboo only distributes mac and linux scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I wrote my own.  It's so much nicer than subversion poll time-outs.  Tested on:

- VisualSvn Server 2.7.2;
- Windows Web Server 2008 R2.
- PowerShell 2.0

### BambooWebApiTrigger.bat

A batch file runner for PowerShell in `C:\SvnHooks\`:

```
@echo OFF
rem this file just makes spawning powershell from VisualSvn a tad easier...
rem
rem Args from VisualSvn Server are ignored. Pass Bamboo BUILD KEY as the first
rem parameter to this script.

Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File C:\SvnHooks\BambooWebApiTrigger.ps1 -key %1
```

### BambooWebApiTrigger.ps1

A PowerShell script to run System.Net.WebClient, also in `C:\SvnHooks\`.  Overwrite *bamboo.yourdefaultdomain.com* with your local Bamboo server:

```
# A Powershell script to trigger Bamboo to build a specific key
param (
    [string]$baseurl = "http://bamboo.radicalsystems.com.au:8085",
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$key,
    [string]$tmp = $null
 )

$fullUrl = $baseurl + "/updateAndBuild.action?buildKey=" + $key
if (!$tmp) {
    $tmp = [io.path]::GetTempFileName()
}

echo "Pinging Bamboo API at '$fullUrl'"
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile($fullUrl, $tmp)

# comment Remove-Item to see the results.  It is a HTML result with success message.
# echo "Results are in $tmp"
Remove-Item $tmp
```

### Configure VisualSvn

Right click on project in VisualSvn Server Manager > Properties > Hooks > Post-commit hook (Edit).

Enter this line after any others:

```
C:\SvnHooks\BambooWebApiTrigger.bat BambooProjectKey
```

where BambooProjectKey is the key, found after your bamboo url when browsing the **Build Plan** (not the project).  It usually has a hyphen in it: `http://bamboo.yourdomain.com:8085/browse/FOO-BAR`.  In this case, FOO-BAR would be the key.

### Configure Bamboo

Change your Bamboo trigger to *Repository triggers the build when changes are committed*

### Options

You can overwrite the key from the VisualSvn post-commit hook dialog, as well as Bamboo base URL and temp file location from the batch file runner.